# Is this a complete sentence? Using colons

Tags: grammaticality, colons, independent-clauses

The sentence I saw: "The eggs benedict should include the following ingredients: poached eggs, English muffins, bacon, and hollandaise sauce."

But colons must follow an independent clause. So does that mean that "The eggs benedict should include the following ingredients." is a complete sentence?

Because I feel like its not a complete sentence if it is not followed by a list.

Comment: It has a subject, a verb, and an object. What did you think was missing from the grammar?

Answer (score -3):

"The eggs benedict should include the following ingredients." is a complete sentence *grammatically* but not *semantically*: "the following" says something will follow, but nothing does.

It's still OK if the list is provided in some other way, such as in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497072/is-this-an-incomplete-sentence) (where it's separated by a period), or perhaps as a bulleted list:

> The eggs benedict should include the following ingredients.
>
> - eggs
> - an English muffin
> - bacon (or ham)
> - Hollandaise sauce

Even then, it would usually have a colon.

Comment: Fwiw, the example given doesn't match the example linked, and the example linked was wrong in any case. There should (technically) be a colon here and there, regardless of the formatting of the list. The linked list is overlong and was cut off for clarity, but the result was a series of sentence fragments.